# ruby-runtime : Failed to initialize in Jenkins | MAC OS Big SUR

Tags: ruby, macos, jenkins, rvm, fastlane

I am trying to setup Jenkins on My MAC OS to configure Fastlane. But seems like this ruby plugin isn't working. I am new to Jenkin environment. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Failure Report]